# Is it acceptable to use role based controllers in a MVC framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, naming-conventions, role-base-authorization

If my site has several user roles say Admin, User, Manager and there are several modules of functionality that may be used by one particular user or by all users how should I go about naming my controllers?

Is it OK to have role based controllers such as an Admin, User and Manager controller as well as controllers for shared functionality such as Products controller?

And for small parts of functionality that is used by only one user role can I keep that inside the user based controller e.g. having all the add/remove/update functionality for product categories can I have that inside the Admin controller or should it have its own controller even though it will only be a few lines of code?

When searching the net for conventions on doing this I am only provided with ways to name the actual file and other sources only explain the controller functionality and not what should and should not be a controller.

If this is subjective I am also happy to take that as an answer, but as it currently stands I am unsure of what is acceptable and whether or not role based controllers are acceptable in the MVC framework.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I have upgraded my ASP.NET MVC project to version 2-beta release 2 and moved admin related stuff to different area.
This way you can keep your controller names related to their function but run them from dedicated area.